# WD 5TB HDD keeps mounting as readOnly

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount, read-only

I have a WesternDigital external(usb3) 5TB hdd that keeps mounting as readonly every time I reconnect it.

The drive was formatted ExFat with diskUtil and is only a few months old.

I've run `sudo fsck_exfat -dy /dev/rdisk3s1` several times, I keep getting results like this.

```
0 clusters were marked used, but not referenced
0 clusters were marked used and CLUST_BAD
21 clusters were marked free, but referenced
** Rechecking main boot region.
** Rechecking alternate boot region.
Write     offset = 0x000006040000  length = 0x040000
fsck_exfat: Couldn't write 262144 bytes at offset 100925440, errno 9: Bad file descriptor
```

I can remount the drive with `sudo mount -u -o rw /Volumes/Clients` and it seems to work mostly fine (found one corrupt file, but since theres tens of thousands of files, I cant check them all).

How do I troubleshoot the drive further? (I've very comfortable with terminal, but more of a software then hardware guy, I would prefer terminal solutions and not 3rd party apps)

I have the drive formatted as ExFat since I have a PC & Mac, but mostly work with MAC, game on PC. I want the data in a format both computers can natively read so I can use the PC as a backup.

Answer (score -1):

The hard disk mounts as a read-only file system because of windows. When windows shuts down, it hibernates instead of completely shutting down.
Connect the hard drive to PC, boot windows and use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + shut down to make a complete shut down of windows. This should solve the problem.

Comment: It's not a obviously not a system partition, as it's exFAT, not NTFS.